# ArrayList toString() method

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, linked-list

I have an array list with multiple LinkedList objects. My main code is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.*;

public class Sort {
public static void main (String[] args){
    int listNum = 0;
    File file = new File("input.txt");

    ArrayList<LinkedList> my_lists = new ArrayList<LinkedList>();

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

            System.out.println("List" + listNum);
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            LinkedList the_list = new LinkedList();
            String[] templist = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");

            for(int i=0; i<templist.length; i++){
                String temp = templist[i];
                the_list.add(temp);
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
            listNum++;
            my_lists.add(the_list);


        }
        sc.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<my_lists.size();i++){
        System.out.println(my_lists.get(i).toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my LinkedList object class:

```
package kruskal;
import java.util.AbstractList;

public class LinkedList {

Node head;

public LinkedList(){
    this.head = null;
}

public void add (Object newData){
    Node cache = head;
    Node current = null;

    if (cache == null)
        current = new Node(newData, null);
        else {


    while ((current = cache.next) != null)
        cache = cache.next;

    cache.next = new Node(newData,null);
        }
}



public Object getFront(){
    return this.head.data;
}

}
```

And my node class:

```
package kruskal;

public class Node {
public Object data;
public Node next;

public Node(Object data,Node next){
    this.data=data;
    this.next=next;
}
}
```

At the end of my main portion of code, I tried doing a for loop that displayed each LinkedList within my ArrayList, but I'm only getting the addresses of the LinkedLists:

```
kruskal.LinkedList@2cc47220
kruskal.LinkedList@1520a9d6
kruskal.LinkedList@136e2b70
kruskal.LinkedList@25e5d007
kruskal.LinkedList@12bc8f01
kruskal.LinkedList@19509443
kruskal.LinkedList@7935c7b0
```

Any idea why my toString() method isn't working? I'm assuming I need the method in my LinkedList class, but what would I be returning?

Comment: Because you haven't overridden the `toString` method in your `LinkedList` class.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you don't have a `toString()` method defined in your `LinkedList` class, so it inherits [the `toString()` method from `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), which is responsible for the output you see.

> In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Override `toString()` in `LinkedList` and return the `String` you want to see printed.

Comment: I want to be able to return the specified (i) LinkedList contained in my ArrayList (my_lists[i]). Would I simply just return my_lists[i]?

Answer (score 2):

You need to **override** the `toString` method of your `LinkedList`.
You could do as follows:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String res = "[";
    Node current = this.head;
    while(current != null) {
        res += current.toString() + "\t";
        current = current.next;
    }

    res += "]";
    return res;
}
```

Of course... you'll then have to override `Node#toString` as well ;)

Sample code:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return data.toString();
}
```

Comment: I'm now getting a null pointer exception. Does my output still need to be     System.out.println(my_lists.get(i).toString()); ?

Comment: Yes, you should keep using this call! Something was actually wrong in my code. I just updated my answer. Could you try with that new version?